# Why my jQuery extension's function act "static"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a custom jQuery extension to handle files for upload.

My stripped version: http://jsfiddle.net/6huV6/

My full version: http://jsfiddle.net/LQrJm/

My problem is that `buildBondye` is called 2 times, but my extension is added 2 x 2 droppers and buttons..

How do I fix this?

Comment: Follow these guidelines: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: just call buildBondye() instead of the each statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get four because for each element in your set of matched elements you're calling the `buildBondye` function, which in turn calls the `addButton` and `addDropper` functions. Those functions use `$this`, which is the entire set of matched elements (so both of them), not only the element for that iteration of `.each()`.

You can fix this by passing a reference to a single element to those two functions, and using that instead:

```
var buildBondye = function () {
    // inside buildBondye this refers to the specific element for the iteration of .each()
    // different to the this inside the $.fn.bondye function
    addButton(this);
    addDropper(this);
}

var addDropper = function (element) {
    $dropper = $('<input type="text" readonly />');
    $dropper.val('drop here');
    $(element).after($dropper);
}

var addButton = function (element) {
    $button = $('<input type="button" />');
    $button.val('browse');
    $button.bind('click', function () {
        $(element).trigger('click');
    });
    $(element).after($button);
}
```

Take a look at [this updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6huV6/2/).

Comment: +1.  If the OP doesn't understand the closure he's using that would also be good to understand.

Comment: Thanks! I thought the `$this = this;` part had the current `.bondye` I understand it now :)